# "udp relay" via openssh socks proxy

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, udp, socks

I'm trying to run a UDP based multiplayer game (dota 2) via the following chain

`dota2 (OS X)-> proxycap -> ssh tunnel -> home machine (OS X) -> internet`

The home machine is running the latest OS X with the ssh port open. Proxycap has SSH configured as the only proxy server. The proxycap FAQ page has this to say about UDP :

> Does ProxyCap support UDP?
>
> ProxyCap can redirect UDP through a SOCKS5 proxy or a chain of SOCKS5
>   proxies. The required condition is that UDP relay must be enabled on
>   the proxy server. Also, if you want to run streaming software or
>   online games from behind SOCKS you need to ensure that the connection
>   to the proxy is fast enough.

Anyway I try to configure some specific app, or all apps and using the ssh server as the designated proxy, however the UDP as the traffic type is greyed out.

1. So, what exactly is a "UDP relay" ?
2. Does SSH natively implement the UDP relay part of the socks5 RFC ?
3. Do I need to install `dante` at home and use `ssh tunneling` to get to it and then chain them together in proxy cap to get the udp traffic option to be tickable ?

p.s., if there is some better way of proxifying steam and dota2 comments would be welcome.